# The history of summations

Tags: reference-request, summation, math-history

How did summations evolve?  For instance, is there an article, book, webpage, etc. that talks about how mathematicians came up with using $\sum_x{ f(x) }$?  I'm very interested on how summations came to be used, and their history.

Comment: In terms of infinite summation—do you know what the Ancient Greek _horror infiniti_ was? Also, Bernoulli did quite a lot of sums (not sure which one—probably all of them). Euler's solution to the Basel problem is quite a huge moment in math history.

Comment: Viete's formula was an infinite product, but it was the first time anyone explicitly wrote out an infinite sum/product in math. It has been noted as the beginning of "the dawn of modern mathematics."

Comment: @columbus8myhw:  I remember reading about the _horror infiniti_ in a math history book.  I'd like to hear more about this, though.  Also, Viete's formula is very interesting.  This is an excellent starting point.

Comment: Could you provide some more hints which info you are expecting? Are you interested in the history of the *symbol* $\sum$ or the *process* of summing up or in the history of *infinite sums*?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Matt's comment above indicates to me that he's more interested in the history of summation rather than the history of its notation, but he also might have an interest in both to some extent.

Comment: @DaviH: I agree with you. Since MathGroff indicates summation via function series which is rather specific, I've asked for more information in order to prevent writing an answer which is not helpful.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer:  I'm interested in a little of both the notation $\sum$, but more importantly, how the process of summations came into use.

Comment: Have you learned anything interesting about this?

Comment: @MJD:  I've learned a little, but I think that my focus has shifted away from this topic.  I'm sorry that this question never took off.  I originally asked this question because I thought that I had discovered a new way of approaching evaluation of definite sums, and I wanted to get more background on them.

Comment: @Matt Thanks!  The reason I ask is that yesterday I got email from a high school student (in Morocco?) looking for information.  They saw this post and mistook me for the author. If you remember anything possibly useful, would you please email me at the address in my profile? Also: I looked into Euler's 1755 paper, cited as the first use of ∑ for summation, and, unsurprisingly, it seems rather different than the modern use. I think he was using it to mean the inverse to a finite-differences operator, similar to the methods explained in §2.6 of _Concrete Mathematics_ (Graham et al).

Comment: My correspondent points out that Cajori has more to say about this.  Summation with limits might have been introduced by Cauchy, and then Pringsheim adapted Cauchy's notation by writing $\infty$ for the upper limit: https://www.quora.com/Who-is-the-first-mathematician-who-use-the-notation-of-Sigma-for-sum